# How to have in table A multiple columns of table B in EF Core

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am trying with no success to have on table which contains two or more columns of another table.

I would like that, but the automatic configuration fail, and require manual configuration in `OnModelCreating`, but I do not know how to do that.

```
public class Collection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Layout? PrimaryLayout { get; set; }
    public Layout? SecondaryLayout { get; set; }
}

public class Layout
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Collection> Collections { get; set; } = new(); // if possible, but not necessary
}
```

Basically, I have a collection if items, and I want to have different kind of layouts to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the property

```
public List<Collection> Collections { get; set; } = new();
```

So, your entities will look like

```
public class Collection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Layout? PrimaryLayout { get; set; }
    public Layout? SecondaryLayout { get; set; }
}

public class Layout
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

If you are okay with these entities, you don't need to write a configuration manually.

Unfortunately, you can't have a single navigation collection for multiple foreign keys, so if it is acceptable, you can use multiple navigation collections

```
public class Collection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Layout? PrimaryLayout { get; set; }
    public Layout? SecondaryLayout { get; set; }
}

public class Layout
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Collection> PrimaryCollections { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Collection> SecondaryCollections { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Also you need to override `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` in your DbContext

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Collection>()
            .HasOne(x => x.PrimaryLayout)
            .WithMany(x => x.PrimaryCollections);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Collection>()
            .HasOne(x => x.SecondaryLayout)
            .WithMany(x => x.SecondaryCollections);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, stupid I am. I believed I tested without the Collections property, but I did not.

Thanks a lot for pointing this out, and also for the configuration with two collections! :)